# if else statement syntax error during for a each loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table being generated with results from a MySQL query. The table was generating fine until I tried to add an 'if else' statement. Now I get this error and have tried to troubleshoot but can't make it work.

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING"

This is the php code

```
<table>

<?php
foreach ($result AS $row) {

printf('
<tr>
<td>');

if(!empty($row['url']))

{
printf('
<img class="parklogo" border="0" src="/images/logos/%s" alt="%s" >' . 

PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']');
}

else
{
printf('
<img src="/images/%s%s-thumb.jpg" alt="%s"/>' . PHP_EOL, $row['url'], 

$row['alt'], $row['alt']');
}

printf('
</td>

<td>
%s<br>
%s<br>
%s

</td>

</tr>

' . PHP_EOL, $row['headline'], $row['Displaydate'],
$row['story'] );

}
?>

</table>
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: There's an unneeded quote at the end of `PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']');`

Comment: Epic win for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last quote in the lines.

`PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']');`

`$row['alt'], $row['alt']'`

to

`PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']);`

`$row['alt'], $row['alt']`

Comment: +1 for mentioning both errors

Comment: A stupid mistake - thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:-

```
PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']');
```

to

```
PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']);  // removed the last single quote
```

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
printf('<img class="parklogo" border="0" src="/images/logos/%s" alt="%s" >' . PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']');
```

to

```
printf('<img class="parklogo" border="0" src="/images/logos/%s" alt="%s" >' . PHP_EOL, $row['logo'], $row['logo']);
```